# Getting same Output array for an image when predict using model.predict()

Tags: machine-learning, conv-neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I am new to neural networks and I am working on prediction from images.I Downloaded a Hand Gesture Recognition code from Kaggle
https://www.kaggle.com/code/benenharrington/hand-gesture-recognition-database-with-cnn
and saved the model using
`model.save('hand-guesture-model.h5')`

so using this model when i tried to predict the image. iam getting the same output array for different images.

code:

```
from keras.models import load_model
import cv2
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

model = load_model('hand-guesture-model.h5')

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='rmsprop',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

img = Image.open('test.jpg').convert('L')
img = img.resize((120, 320))
arr = np.array(img, dtype = 'float32')
arr = arr.reshape(1,120, 320,1)

prediction = model.predict(arr)
print(prediction)
np.argmax(prediction[0])
```

result:

```
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 77ms/step
[[1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

No matter what image i use iam getting same answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model requires the input image to be in the range 0-1, not 0-255
So, scaling the image pixel values by dividing it by 255 should fix your problem. Here is the full code:

```
from keras.models import load_model
import cv2
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

model = load_model('hand-guesture-model.h5')

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='rmsprop',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

img = Image.open('test.jpg').convert('L')
img = img.resize((120, 320))
arr = np.array(img, dtype = 'float32')
arr = arr.reshape(1,120, 320,1)
arr = arr/255.0 # Scale pixel values

prediction = model.predict(arr)
print(prediction)
np.argmax(prediction[0])
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I tried scaling the image as you told and i got something like this
[[9.9895275e-01 8.1604760e-04 1.7146566e-07 2.1835438e-09 2.0120385e-04
  2.6909429e-05 2.2199329e-06 4.6790056e-09 7.2497919e-09 5.4266911e-07]]
How do i know which classification it is.

Comment: @ShanthanReddy The output is probabilities of classes. The index with the maximum probability is the prediction. You can use `np.argmax()` to find the index with the highest probability.

Comment: thanks for the answer. when I predict using the images https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/gti-upm/leapgestrecog that are used for training the model the output accuracy is high. but when I click a photo of my hand and use that for prediction, the accuracy decreases by a lot may i know why that is happening

Comment: @ShanthanReddy The images used for training are different from real world instances. The images used for training are black-and-white with no background, so the model can only be used for such type of images.

Comment: thanks for the answer. it helped a lot. but how do I map the output I got from `np.argmax()` to the label? first, I manually made a dictionary using the images and their prediction values. but when I retrained the model, I am getting different values for `np.argmax()` of same image, and the dictionary i made is not helpful

Comment: @ShanthanReddy I need to see your code to fix the issue. So post your problem as a question on SO.